# Extracting Selected Options from Chosen jQuery plugin as 'val1','val2'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-chosen

```
$(".chosen-select").on('change', function(evt, params) {
    var options = $('#selectID').val();
    var values = options.join();
    console.log(values);
```

```html
<form action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
        <select id="selectID" multiple class='chosen-select'></select>
</form>
```

So I'm trying to get the selected options from chosen jquery into a specific format to be used in a query ("NAME IN (" + values + ")";). But in order for me to do that I need the values of my variables to be in the format of 'option1','option2'. But when I do console.log(value): Im getting my output as 'option1, option2'.

Comment: You turn your array into a single string by using `join()` in this line `var values = options.join();`. That is why you get that output.

Comment: @Geshode but then how would i use values into the query then?

Comment: You would have to loop through the array to add quotes at the beginning and end of each element and then you can join them to create a string in which each element has its own quotes around it. That way the query should recognize it as individual elements rather than as one string.